# Implementation of super MultiValue map

Tags: java

Is there any ready implementation of super MultiValue map?

I need a map

```
SuperMap<List<String>, List<String>> superMap
```

where `key` List is set of keys, and value List is `set` of values.

`keys: {a, b, c}` and values for any of these keys are `values: {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}`
It means that key `a` should have a values `{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}` as well as the key `b` and `c`.

**Updated with requirements from comments**

I need to get all keys of one group? For example I need to get collection of keys for one similar value. In that case I cannot use your approach `map.put("a", value);` because I need to group (`a, b` it is first group, and `c` is related to second group).

*UPD2*

I'm looking for a simple and much concise solution to replace this code

```
Map<List<String>, List<String>> ops = new HashMap<List<String>, List<String>>() {{
        put(asList("a", "aaa"), asList("1", "2"));
        put(asList("b", "bbb"), asList("3", "4"));
}};

public static List<String> values(String optionKey) {
    for (List<String> key : ops.keySet()) {
        for (String k : key) {
            if (optionKey.equals(k)) {
                return ops.get(key);
            }
        }
     }
     return Collections.emptyList();
 }
```

with some smart impl form any well known lib (Google Guava or something).

Comment: Why not use a map string,list and set for key `a` value `{1,2,3,4,5}`, for key `b` also value `{1,2,3,4,5}` and so on?

Comment: How can this improve the `MultiValue` map?

Comment: I'm looking for a ready implementation. If I wouldn't find any I'll implement it myself.

Comment: I'm not talking about implementing yourself. I'm talking about using a normal Map (e.g. HashMap)

Comment: What you're asking for is a normal `Map`

Comment: http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/ListMultimap.html

Comment: Is the order of the list (you like to use as key) important? Is the order of the list (you like to use as value) important?

Comment: HashMap is too verbose. I need to write `HashMap<List<String>, List<String>>`. And if I have map of maps? Too much generics.

Comment: No. `HashMap<String, List<String>>`.

Comment: @user1121883 Nice. Will check it.

Comment: @m0skit0 But what if I have different keys for only one group of values?

Comment: @PeterRader Yes, order of list is important to me.

Comment: I've written an answer with an example of what I mean.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're overcomplicating your data structure. You can simply use `HashMap` or similar implementation.

```
Map<String, List<String>> map = new LinkedHashMap<>();
List<String> value = new ArrayList<>();

// Fill the value list here...

map.put("a", value);
map.put("b", value);
map.put("c", value);
```

Comment: The OP mentioned in a comment that the order matters. Can you change your answer to be a `LinkedHashMap`?

Comment: Ok. But if I need to get all keys of one group? For example I need to get collection of keys for one similar value. In that case I cannot use your approach `map.put("a", value);` because I need to group (`a, b` it is first group, and `c` is related to second group).

Comment: @barbara In that case this is not a valid solution. Anyway, that was not stated in your question or comments, was it? Next time please take your time and specify exactly what behavior you need, so neither you nor me waste our time :)

Comment: @Ascalonian Yes, you're right, although I think it doesn't matter anymore.